# Canvas - image opacity loop (fade in)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

guys. here is a bit of code that is supposed to be okay, though it doesn't work...heh...quite typical =)

```
function xxx() {

    var txtCanvas = document.getElementById('text');
    var textOne = txtCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var alpha = 0.5;
    textOne.globalAlpha = alpha;
    // loading image
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://tvangeste.com/gallery/selani/tv4_2.jpg"
    img.onload = function () {
        textOne.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    }
    //end of image loader

    if (alpha < 1) 
    {
      alpha += 0.1;

   }



}    
requestAnimationFrame(xxx);
```

This is Fiddle to show how it doesn't work...
http://jsfiddle.net/gLs1owd6/

The script is supposed to do one simple thing - to fade in the image. 
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop to be able to redraw the image at various opacity levels. For a loop you need something that doesn't block UI as well as refreshing with each monitor update, so, requestAnimationFrame to the rescue.

Here is one way to go about this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {

    // when image has loaded we can use it.
    // this is a self-invoking function used to fade in the image
    (function loop() {
        // we can update the property directly
        textOne.globalAlpha += 0.01;

        // as we have opacity involved we need to clear the canvas each time
        textOne.clearRect(0, 0, txtCanvas.width, txtCanvas.height);

        // redraw the image
        textOne.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // if not full opacity, loop (canvas will clamp the value for us)
        if (textOne.globalAlpha < 1.0) {
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);    
        }
        else {
            // when done, call the next step from here...
        }
    })();

}

// set source as last step for image loading
img.src = "http://tvangeste.com/gallery/selani/tv4_2.jpg"
```

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLs1owd6/16/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I certainly does, sire! Thanks a lot!